# Bind path in singularity using container environment variable

Tags: singularity-container, apptainer

I have a singularity container built with a [scientific filesystem](https://sylabs.io/guides/latest/user-guide/definition_files.html#scif-apps) app.
I run the container with `singularity run --app myapp image.sif` and, accordingly, I have the environment variable `SCIF_APPDATA=/scif/data/myapp` set inside the container.

I'd like to bind a path using this environment variable. Something like:

```
singularity run -B /my/path/on/host/:$SCIF_APPDATA/input/
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I didn't manage to make singularity use as a mount path the environment variable with its "internal" value.

I have to explicitly pass the value of the environment variable:

```
singularity run -B /my/path/on/host/:/scif/data/myapp/input
```

Does anybody know how to use container environment variables in bind paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to directly use environment variables from inside the container in the bind statement.  However, you can do it in two steps, first a call to `singularity exec` to get the value of the variable, then use it with `singularity run`:

```
SCIF_APPDATA=$(singularity exec ascisoftApp.sif bash -c "echo \$SCIF_APPDATA")
singularity run -B /my/path/on/host/:$SCIF_APPDATA/input/ ...
```

Don't forget the backslash to escape the $ in the echo command.

Note: Not sure why but it doesn't work for me when I directly use `echo`, hence the wrapping with `bash -c`.